# Adding Discount percentage on Magento 2 Special Price

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Using Magento 2.1 I have overridden the final_price.phtml  and uploaded to my theme however when adding the following calculation to echo the amount in % the cuistomer will save, the price disappears. Any thoughts on what is throwing the spanner in my cogs?

```
<?php $specialPrice = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSpecialPrice(), 'special_price');
$standardPrice = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getPrice(), 'price');
$Save = ((($standardPrice - $specialPrice) / $standardPrice)*100);?>
<?php echo round($Save,2) . '%'; ?>
```

I have also edited like so...

```
<?php $specialPrice = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$standardPrice = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');
$Save = ((($standardPrice - $specialPrice) / $standardPrice)*100);?>
<?php echo round($Save,2) . '%'; ?>
```

Comment: YOu want to show save price

Comment: First of all it wont conside for this as a special Price

Comment: Yes for example if the regular price = £20 and the Special Price = £10 then I want to echo Save 50%

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModeuleName\Helper;


class Offer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    public function DisplayDiscountLabel($_product)
    {
        $originalPrice = $_product->getPrice();
        $finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();

        $percentage = 0;
        if ($originalPrice > $finalPrice) {
            $percentage = number_format(($originalPrice - $finalPrice) * 100 / $originalPrice,0);
        }

        if ($percentage) {
            return $percentage."% Off";
        }

    }
}
```

In your **`.phtml`** use this

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Vendor\ModuleName\Helper\Offer')->DisplayDiscountLabel($_product); ?>
```

Comment: mmm something is a miss here. It is not loading the product pages now. I have ran the upgrade and enable module commands. Any ideas before I try debug?

Comment: put di:compile then check log

Comment: This is the error:  https://goo.gl/9TUqfh

Comment: Check Weather Helper Data you created or not

Comment: I am at the end! What is it I have missed? https://goo.gl/4adFyV Ive tried all different methods and it is not rendering

Comment: did you call this in your list.phtml <?php echo $this->helper('Vendor\ModuleName\Helper\Offer')->DisplayDiscountLabel($_product); ?>